# Instantiating a prefab and then setting each prefab different variables

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set a special ID on a "int" variable for each of my prefabs when it is in instantiated.

I'm currently using 2 scripts. My prefab handler script and a game handler script. I'm setting the variable in the game handler script and using random.range to generate a random number, I also have a function to ensure that non of the ID's for my prefabs will be the same. This works. Now I am attempting to assign the values that I have in my game handler script i.e prefabIdOne, prefabIdTwo, prefabIdThree to the prefabId variable in the prefab handler script.

I have attempted to use `Prefab.GetComponent<prefabHandler>` however i assume this will target all prefabs so will not work. I have also tried to target the gameObject instead of the script however as I assumed this also did not work.

Full run down of my code is here:

Setting Variable:

```
 horses = 0;
        horseOneRaceId = Random.Range(1 , 7);
        horseTwoRaceId = Random.Range(1 , 7);
        horseThreeRaceId = Random.Range(1 , 7);
        horseFourRaceId = Random.Range(1 , 7);
        horseFiveRaceId = Random.Range(1 , 7);
        horseSixRaceId = Random.Range(1 , 7);
        while (horseTwoRaceId == horseOneRaceId)
        {
            horseTwoRaceId = Random.Range(1 , 7);
        }
        
        while(horseThreeRaceId == horseOneRaceId || horseThreeRaceId == horseTwoRaceId)
        {
            horseThreeRaceId = Random.Range(1 , 7);
        }

        while (horseFourRaceId == horseOneRaceId || horseFourRaceId == horseTwoRaceId || horseFourRaceId == horseThreeRaceId)
        {
            horseFourRaceId = Random.Range(1 , 7);
        }

        while (horseFiveRaceId == horseOneRaceId || horseFiveRaceId == horseTwoRaceId || horseFiveRaceId == horseThreeRaceId || horseFiveRaceId == horseFourRaceId)
        {
            horseFiveRaceId = Random.Range(1 , 7);
        }

        while (horseSixRaceId == horseOneRaceId || horseSixRaceId == horseTwoRaceId || horseSixRaceId == horseThreeRaceId || horseSixRaceId == horseFourRaceId || horseSixRaceId == horseFiveRaceId)
        {
            horseSixRaceId = Random.Range(1 , 7);
        }
```

HorseHandler script has this variable

```
public static int raceId;
```

This is how I am trying to Instantiate and assign the variable when instantiating:

```
 if (horses == 0)
    {
        horseOne = Instantiate(_HorsePrefab);
        _HorsePrefab.name = "Horse (1)";
        horseOne.GetComponent<HorseHandler>().RealRaceID = horseOneRaceId;
        
        horses++;
    }
    if (horses == 1)
    {
        horseTwo = Instantiate(_HorsePrefab);
        _HorsePrefab.name = "Horse (2)";
        horseTwo.GetComponent<HorseHandler>();
        HorseHandler.raceId = horseTwoRaceId;
        horses++;
    }
    if (horses == 2)
    {
        horseThree = Instantiate(_HorsePrefab);
        _HorsePrefab.name = "Horse (3)";
        horseThree.GetComponent<HorseHandler>();
        HorseHandler.raceId = horseThreeRaceId;
        horses++;
    }
    if (horses == 3)
    {
        horseFour = Instantiate(_HorsePrefab);
        _HorsePrefab.name = "Horse (4)";
        horseFour.GetComponent<HorseHandler>();
        HorseHandler.raceId = horseFourRaceId;
        horses++;
    }
    if (horses == 4)
    {
        horseFive = Instantiate(_HorsePrefab);
        _HorsePrefab.name = "Horse (5)";
        horseFive.GetComponent<HorseHandler>();
        HorseHandler.raceId = horseFiveRaceId;
        horses++;
    }
    if (horses == 5)
    {
        horseSix = Instantiate(_HorsePrefab);
        _HorsePrefab.name = "Horse (6)";
        horseSix.GetComponent<HorseHandler>();
        HorseHandler.raceId = horseSixRaceId;
        horses++;
    }
```

This is the inspector for GameHandler script where I am instantiating objects:
[image]

All the instantiated game objects have the same raceId which is always the value of horseRaceIdSix (the last assigned value to HorseHandler.race)

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Well once you instantiate it you can get its components and set their values

Comment: How do i do this?

Comment: When using "HorseHandler.raceId = horseOneRaceId;" across several horses however = horseTwoRaceId, they all end up the same, because Im calling from the script so its changing all scripts, how do I access a particular game objects script?

Comment: Well as you havent shown the horsehandler script if its changing all it suggests that script has a static variable as you already show code getting w component from a game object i dont think you need you are struggling with that. And they all end up the same as horseoneraceid doesnt change value

Comment: I will edit the post showing all the code

Comment: I have updated this post now

Comment: As i said earlier horsehandler raceid is static. So its not per horse.

Comment: if i change it from non static i get an error, how do i combat this>

Comment: I give up.  Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

So I've actually read abit here using this link: https://answers.unity.com/questions/235836/what-exactly-is-static.html

Probably basic for most people but for beginners or even people that haven't done much using static/non static.

**Static** is assigned to the class, meaning that all versions of my instantiated prefab shared the same value.

**Non static** will allow you to give the prefab (or any gameobject) different values even when having the same script.

When trying to call a static variable like so:

```
horseFour.GetComponent<HorseHandler>();
    HorseHandler.raceId = horseFourRaceId;
```

You will recieve an error asking you to give an object reference due to non static field.

Using the following code `horseFour.GetComponent<HorseHandler>().raceId = horseFourRaceId;` removes the error and I assume this is because you are firstly calling the gameobject then getting the component and then the script and then the variable all in one instance, instead of referencing the script as an individual not with the game object like above.